# Facebook Paper-like table cells animation

Tags: ios, uitableview, animation

I'm trying to implement transition used in settings menu in Facebook's Paper app: http://blog.brianlovin.com/design-details-paper-by-facebook/#1. I'm using my custom UIViewControllerAnimatedTransitioning object, but I can't achieve the same effect, no matter what type of animation I'm using. So I have some questions:

1) Which animation is used? It looks like cells start to move really fast, and then halt to their final position. Looks like I need POPDecayAnimation, but the result isn't even close.

2) Is delay between animations achieved with setting animation's beginTime depending on cell's index? Or first cells have bigger velocity than last cells?

Comment: Are you talking about wave transition effect?

Comment: https://www.cocoacontrols.com/controls/amwavetransition

Comment: @Injectios looks very good! gonna try it

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As Injectios suggested [AMWaveTransition](https://www.cocoacontrols.com/controls/amwavetransition) is kinda close to Paper's animation. I ended up using it with some adjustments.

I also asked this question on pop github page, you can view it [here](https://github.com/facebook/pop/issues/166). Their answer might be useful if you want to implement this animation yourself:

> Hey! I implemented that in Paper. The animations on each cell are POPSpringAnimations, and they're connected together by (every frame) updating the toValue of each animation to point to the current value of the one before. Hope that helps!

Answer (score -1):

1. In cellForRowAtIndexPath, use UIViewAnimation block.
2. Set cell properties as per your requirement:

   - indentationLevel
   - indentationWidth
   - shouldIndentWhileEditing
3. Then in animation block, change frame position.
4. For example for first cell, indetationLevel = 1, and indentationWidth = cell.frame.size.width, then update it to indetationLevel = 0 and indentationWidth = 0 in that animation block. And for the further cells you can multiply this values by (cellIndexPath+1)
5. For more details visit : https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/Documentation/UIKit/Reference/UITableViewCell_Class/index.htm

P.S.: Update the logic as per your requirement